# How can I detect if my chrome packaged app is installed?

Tags: push-notification, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-app

I am the owner of a chrome app which is currently a hosted app on https://mydomain.com.  I would like to add push messaging to it, so it will have to become a packaged app.

However, I don't want to lose the ability to prompt users on the website to install the app if they don't already have it installed.

There are many ways I've come up with to test this, but none of them seem satisfactory:

- **`chrome.app.isInstalled`**, the method I currently use is unavailable for packaged apps.
- **Inserting a DOM element** is a recommended practice, but only available for extensions; `content_scripts` is disallowed for packaged apps.
- **Setting a cookie** could work, but the `cookies` permission is disallowed for packaged apps.
- **Setting a cookie using a webview** might be possible, but webviews are sandboxed, and do not share cookies with chrome.
- **Detecting a file in the app** might work, but the `web_accessible_resources` permission is disallowed disallowed for packaged apps.
- **Specifying `url handlers`** seems like it might work, but It looks like they only work for urls in the address bar (i.e. they don't seem to handle requests).
- **Setting `externally_connectable`** works, but it requires a permissions dialog saying that the app would like to "communicate with cooperating websites".  The permission is this vague even if I specify https://mydomain.com.  I would like to avoid this since people tend not to update apps when permissions change.

Does anyone know of a way to determine whether my packaged app is installed if I own both the app and https://mydomain.com?

Answer (score 2):

[`url_handlers`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/url_handlers) or [`externally_connectable`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/externally_connectable) is the way to go. You've understandably ruled out the last option because of the extra permission warning (which would disable the app until the user approves the new permission).

`url_handlers` does offer a solution without requiring extra permissions:

1. At your server's side, if the user doesn't have any cookies, redirect to some other URL at your server. E.g. `http://example.com/landing/` -> `http://example.com/landing/?noapp`.
2. If the app is not installed, the redirect will be followed. On that landing page, use `history.replaceState(null, null, '/landing/');` to change the URL back to the original URL.
3. If the app is installed, the [`chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime#event-onLaunched) will be triggered, and the redirect is not followed. On your website, use `setTimeout` to check whether or not the page is unloaded.

---

If the previous method doesn't suit you for some reason, then there is one more (fragile) alternative: Set up an API endpoint at your server and use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). Because your app does not have the permission to access this resource, the AJAX request automatically gets an unforgeable request header (`Origin: chrome-extension://.../...`). You can detect the presence of this header, and mark the app as installed for the specific IP address. If you choose a right frequency, you will have an up-to-date ip-to-app mapping.
This doesn't work for multiple computers behind a NAT though. And I (as a user) would be concerned about my privacy if you kept pinging home...

Comment: I have not yet had a chance to verify this, but it looks like it's on the right track.  I'll report back when I try this out.